SwiftDotenv is not loading the keys
I am using the SwiftDotenv package located at https://github.com/thebarndog/swift-dotenv.git. I created a file called .env and have my keys and values.
When I call
import SwiftDotenv

// load in environment variables
try Dotenv.configure()

It throws exception saying
 Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftDotenv.Dotenv.LoadingFailure.environmentFileIsMissing

Isn't it suppose to read .env file by default. Why is it not able to read the file?
UPDATED:
@main
struct LearnApp: App {
    
    
    init() {
        try!  try! Dotenv.configure(atPath: "development.env", overwrite: false)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack {
                Text("View")
            }
        }
    }
}



Please show a [mre]. Where did you put the .env file and what is the working directory when you run your code? How did you run your code?

@Sweeper Added code to show where the error is thrown. Also attached a screenshot. In the docs it says that it defaults to .env I tried it and it still threw the same exception.

You should pass the correct path to the .env file. Assuming the .env file is copied as a bundle resource (check the "Copy Bundle Resources" step in the Build Phases if you are not sure), you can use url(forResource:withExtension:) to get a URL.
let envPath = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "development", withExtension: "env")!.path()
try! Dotenv.configure(atPath: envPath , overwrite: false)

